# Trying to make two custom buttons in NetSuite one works the other does not

Tags: html, templates, button, printing, netsuite

I am trying to add a second custom button in NetSuite to print item labels. If you click the first button the pdf template opens to print a sheet of labels. The second button is suppose to open a template to print one label per sheet for a zebra printer. If I paste the address in that I linked to the button and manually put in the recordId I can get the template to pop up, just not through the button.

UserEvent:

```html
function UserEventAddPrintBtn() {
try {
var internalId = nlapiGetRecordId();
var button1 = form.addButton('custpage_button1', 'Print Item Labels (Sheet)',"irlabelBtn()");
//set the internal id of the created Client script.

var button2 = form.addButton('custpage_button2', 'Print Item Labels (Zebra)',"irlabelBtn2()");
//set the internal id of the created Client script.
form.setScript('customscript_atn_client_rec_label');
 
}
catch (exception) {
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Error in AddButton()', exception);
}
}
```

Client Script

```html
function irlabelBtn() {
    var recordId = nlapiGetRecordId();
   var baseUrl = '/app/common/custom/advancedprint/printsearchresults.nl?printType=SEARCH&l=T&e=T&id=1150&style=NORMAL&sortcol=Transction_ORDTYPE9_raw&sortdir=ASC&searchid=1150&csv=Export&printtemplate=146&Transaction_INTERNALID=';
    var windowUrl = baseUrl + recordId;
  //alert (recordId);
  
    window.open(windowUrl);
}

function irlabelBtn2() {
    var recordId2 = nlapiGetRecordId();
   var baseUrl2 = '/app/common/custom/advancedprint/printsearchresults.nl?printType=SEARCH&l=T&e=T&id=1150&style=NORMAL&sortcol=Transction_ORDTYPE9_raw&sortdir=ASC&searchid=1150&csv=Export&printtemplate=147&Transaction_INTERNALID=';
    var windowUrl2 = baseUrl2 + recordId2;
  //alert (recordId2);
  
    window.open(windowUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, checked my client script and it worked.

```html
function irlabelBtn() {
    var recordId = nlapiGetRecordId();
   var baseUrl = '/app/common/custom/advancedprint/printsearchresults.nl?printType=SEARCH&l=T&e=T&id=1150&style=NORMAL&sortcol=Transction_ORDTYPE9_raw&sortdir=ASC&searchid=1150&csv=Export&printtemplate=146&Transaction_INTERNALID=';
    var windowUrl = baseUrl + recordId;
  //alert (recordId);
  
    window.open(windowUrl);
}

function irlabelBtn2() {
    var recordId = nlapiGetRecordId();
    var baseUrl = '/app/common/custom/advancedprint/printsearchresults.nl?printType=SEARCH&l=T&e=T&id=1150&style=NORMAL&sortcol=Transction_ORDTYPE9_raw&sortdir=ASC&searchid=1150&csv=Export&printtemplate=147&Transaction_INTERNALID=';
    var windowUrl = baseUrl + recordId;
  //alert (recordId2);
  
    window.open(windowUrl);
}
```